# Google Sign In shows 500 error on iOS

Tags: ios, google-api

I followed the official guide, and checked clientID is setup correctly and URL scheme is registered.

Here is my code:

ApplicationDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // Setup Google SingIn
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "363974216099-mnrmo2bhkg9lttb6j891g1qvdqlccr4v.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes = 
            ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login",                                           
             "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"]


        return true
    }

    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url as URL?,
                sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
    }
```

The delegates are set in ViewController and they are not even executed.
The url scheme is registered, here is .plist:
[image]

I tried on both: simulator and device. And I always get this:
[image]

If I call signInSilently, the delegate method is called with error:
`The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.GIDSignIn error -4.)`

Comment: have you added 'GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes'

Comment: No. Do I need one?

Comment: yes, you have to add 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login' like GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login") . GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me")

Comment: I added the scopes and updated the post and it didn't help, still shows the same error.

Comment: GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently() add this to. As I hope you have added correct bundle ID and activate Google login from Google Console.

Comment: I tried to login with signInSilently and it calls a delegate with error. The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.GIDSignIn error -4.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177781/discussion-between-piyushrathi-and-semyon-tikhonenko).

Answer (score 0):

I made it work. You need to setup OAuth Consent screen in Credentials section. You need to select email address.